# how to retrive value from database if user check two or more checkbox and display value via a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hye all expert, i have a page (history.php) that retrieve their old data after user login:- beside each TITLE there a check box,

```
        TITLE   
 <checkbox> BAT101
 <checkbox> BAT102  
 <checkbox> BAT201  

 <button> COMPARE SELECTED
```

for example, let say if user check checkbox for BAT101 and BAT201 then click button COMPARE SELECTED then go to the new page .php that will display like this:-

```
 TITLE       PERCENTAGE RESULT
 BAT 101         30%
 BAT 201         50.2%
```

The data for percentage result were stored in a database, same with the title..
Anyone know the source code should i implement?
This is my code for history.php currently..many thanks...!!

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['idmember'])){

$idmembersession = $_SESSION['idmember'];
}
include'configure.php';
?>

<html>
<title>History Page</title><head></head>
<body>
<table>

    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>TITLE</th>
        <th>ACTION</th>

    </tr>

     <?php
          $query = "SELECT * FROM documents where idmember='$idmembersession'";
      $sql_query = mysql_query($query) or die('Error 3 :'.mysql_error());
          while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query,MYSQL_ASSOC)){

                        $title = $data['subject'];

 ?>

<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<?php echo $title ?>" /></td>

    <?php
        echo "<td>$title</td>";

}

?>
</tr>

</table> 

  <a href="#" class="button green">Compare selected</a>   
</body></html>
```

Comment: can you please clarify , what you want to do??

Comment: @CyberBoy i want to retrieve data from database if user create multiple selected checkbox but i don't know the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this for creating check box...
`<input type="checkbox" name="selectedcheck[<?php echo $title ?>]" value="<?php echo $title.'=>'.$iddoc; ?>" />`
it will create a array with name selectedcheck[].

in the newpage.php you can catch this array of selected check box by this using

```
<?php
if(isset ($_POST["vehicle"]))
{
$selectedcheckbox = $_POST["selectedcheck"];
foreach($selectedcheckbox as $title=>$value)
  {
   echo $title . " Value=" . $value;
  }
}
?>
```